# c# Dynamically creating an EventHandler in a loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to dynamically create an array of images on a form.  THe images are rendering okay, but I cannot work out how to create the eventHandlers.

```
    pictureBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox);
```

This line is causing be problems.

```
 private void frmBorderlessMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       int top = 10;
       int left = 10;
       int width = 200;
       int height = 150;
       var uutNames = MyObject.GetNames().ToArray();
       var uutImages = MyObject.GetImages().ToArray();
       for (int i = 0; i < uutNames.Length; i++)
       {
           System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();


           Image newImage = Image.FromFile(uutImages[i]+".png");
           pictureBox.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(newImage));
           pictureBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(left, top);
           pictureBox.Name = "pictureBox"+i;
           pictureBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 150);
           pictureBox.SizeMode =   
                     System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
           pictureBox.TabIndex = i;
           pictureBox.TabStop = false;

           pictureBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox);
           this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
           left += width + 10;
           if ( (i > 0 ) && (i % 3) == 0)
           {
                    top += height + 10;
                    left = 10;
           }
       }
   }
```

Additional Info:
Upon clicking the image I would like a new form to open displaying details about the entity that was clicked.  It will be the same form, but will be loaded with data depending on which image was clicked on.

Comment: It's unclear what you *want* to happen when the pictureBox is clicked.

Comment: Create a method with EventHandler signature and add it to Click event. 
es. void ManageClick(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

Comment: "This line is causing be problems." what problems?

Comment: You should be able to have VS insert a new method for that event by tabbing twice; then you wont need to do anything, let the UI do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pictureBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox);
```

That is not how event handlers are used.

Lambda:

```
pictureBox.Click += (sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine("HELP I WAS CLICKED OMG");
```

Or with a function:

```
pictureBox.Click += PictureBox_Click;

....

private void PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Stop clicking me >:(");
}
```

Comment: I can get your method to work.  But how can I get the PictureBox_Click() method to display which pictureBox was clicked.  It would be handy if I can pass the 'i' or the pictureBox.TabIndex to the method.   I guess with this implementation each pictureBox is using the same click handler.

Comment: the `sender` variable is the control that has caused the click event. Cast it to PictureBox and you got it.

Comment: Thanks Longoon - I have grasped it now.